# Left join returns nulls even thought there should be rows with data

Tags: sql, join, hive

My script

```
select concat(stg.columns)
from stg
```

returns 30451 row of data

when I do this

```
select concat(stg.columns, '|', sim.column)
from stg
left join db.sub sim
on stg.key = sim.no
where sim.exp is null
```

I get 30451 row of nulls

Why is that?

For example I have this row when first query is executed.

```
9035139223|M|10.0|1
```

and there is this row in the sim table

```
no          exp   sim.column
9035139223  NULL  250997252877782
```

So the result should be

9035139223|M|10.0|1|250997252877782

Comment: Are you joining on the right column? Or maybe it's because you are concatenating with a `NULL` value (the sim.column).

Comment: Trailing spaces? All you have to do is show us one couple of values that you think should match

Comment: In concat if any one column is null then whole result will be run for that row. What is the result of this query :- select concat (stg.columns) from stg where concat(stg.columns) is null.

Comment: @AshishSingh I don't think there is a point for that query since it's like `select null from stg where stg.columns is null`. You don't get much information out of it, especially information to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Agree .. I just want to be sure that concat is done on null value .. It will return the same result 30451.

Comment: It's hard to tell in this format. Please add the result of `hex(stg.key)` and `hex(sim.no)` for this values

Comment: @Dudu Seems like there were trailing spaces. Changing to `trim(sim.no)` helped.

Comment: @Radu Because `sim.no` had trailing spaces, `sim.column` was null. Changing to `trim(sim.no)` helped.

Comment: Classic :-) ....